Why is Margayya's money said to be ill-earned?
In R. K. Narayan's novel The Financial Expert, why was the money earned by Margayya said to be ill-earned?
What I believe is that he's worked very hard to earn that money.
And the theme of the book is lust for money. Which makes me think, why? Everyone wants to earn money. What is wrong in that? How does the story say that Margayya earned money, and it was ill-earned?

Where does it say in the novel that the money was ill-earned? Could you quote the relevant passage(s)?
